# I'm trying to add pictureboxs to an array so I can reference them later as they are being created programmatically

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

So far all I have is this code...

```
Dim lineb As New PictureBox
lineb.Size = New Size(24, 24)
lineb.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 192, 192)
lineb.Location = New Drawing.Point(xb, yb)
Controls.Add(lineb)
lineb.Name = "lineb" + CStr(creatorb)
creatorb += 1
```

This generates a infinite line of pictureboxs as it is inside a timer.tick event. Xb and Yb continuously move and this works. I need to figure out how to add each picturebox to an array or another way to reference them later. Each one gets created and renamed to lineb + 1...2...3...4... etc.

Comment: They are already part of a collection that you can access later, `Controls`. But if you want to keep another collection of references for some reason, all you'd have to do is create a List(Of PictureBox) and add lineb to it the same way you're adding it to Controls

Comment: If you are adding a new picturebox every tick, you are going to run out of resources very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a way to keep track of dynamically created controls.  It will be easier than adding every control to an array.

```
Dim pbox as New PictureBox
With pbox
     .location = New Point(xb, yb)
     .size = New Size(24, 24)
     .Tag = "box1" 'choose a tag that will help identify it later
     ' and so on
     Addhandler pbox.click, AddressOf pbox_click '' to add a click event handler  
End With
Me.Controls.add(pbox)


Private Sub pbox_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim the_sender As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    Dim reference As String = DirectCast(the_sender.tag, String)

    ''' do whatever you need to do now that you know which picturebox was clicked.

End Sub
```

Alternatively you can always loop through your controls to find the one you are looking for:

```
 For Each Ctrl As Control In Me.Controls

     If TypeOf Ctrl Is PictureBox Then

         If ctrl.tag = "box1" Then '''or whetever you are looking for

             ''' do your stuff here                     

         End If

     End If

 Next
```